# Dynamic sections and rows UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ipad

I am new to iOS,

I am developing `UITableView` with Dynamic rows and sections

I want to display all "today" data in first section, "tomorrow" in other section and "Sunday" in other section and so on...

Code I have tried is,

Here is my Array:

```
 {
      "callbackSlotId": "1234-1234-3214-1233",
      "callbackSlotName": "10:00-10:30",
      "day": "today",
      "availablenow": true
    },
    {
      "callbackSlotId": "1234-1234-3214-1234",
      "callbackSlotName": "11:00-11:30",
      "day": "today",
      "availablenow": false
    },
    {
      "callbackSlotId": "1234-1234-3214-1235",
      "callbackSlotName": "10:30-11:00",
      "day": "today",
      "availablenow": false
    },
    {
      "callbackSlotId": "1234-1234-3214-1236",
      "callbackSlotName": "10:30-11:00",
      "day": "tomorrow",
      "availablenow": false
    },
    {
      "callbackSlotId": "1234-1234-3214-1237",
      "callbackSlotName": "10:30-11:00",
      "day": "tomorrow",
      "availablenow": false
   },
{
  "callbackSlotId": "1234-1234-3214-1241",
  "callbackSlotName": "10:30-11:00",
  "day": "Sunday",
  "availablenow": false
}
...
...
...
```

Using this code it displays all data in multiple sections:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [Array count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [Array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}
```

Can any one help me?
**Thanks for reading**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but you can use idea of my code for separating your array

```
NSMutableArray *sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *elementsInSection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dict in Array) {
    NSString *day = [dict objectForKey:@"day"];
    if (![sections containsObject:day]) {
        [sections addObject:day];
        NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [arr addObject:dict];
        [elementsInSection addObject:arr];
    } else {
        NSMutableArray *arr = [elementsInSection objectAtIndex:[sections indexOfObject:day]];
        [arr addObject:dict];
        [elementsInSection setObject:arr atIndexedSubscript:[sections indexOfObject:day]];
    }
}
```

And your tableview datasource is now become

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [sections count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [elementsInSection count];
}
```

Comment: Just replace  `[elementsInSection addObject:day];` with         `[elementsInSection addObject:arr];`

Comment: Thanks it works but last doubt how do i display valueForKey called `callbackSlotName` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Each element in  elementsInSection is a array of NSDictionary, and each NSDictionary has form 
  `"callbackSlotId": "1234-1234-3214-1234",
      "callbackSlotName": "11:00-11:30",
      "day": "today",
      "availablenow": false
    }`
So you just access by 
`NSDictionary *dict = [[elementsInSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this scenario, you can first separate the `Array` into distinct Sub-Arrays on basis of value of `day` variable.
For this you can use `NSPredicate`

So suppose you main `Array` have 3 distinct values - `today, tomorrow, Sunday` then your Array will have 3 Sub-Arrays

- Array[0] will contain all objects with `day` as `today`
- Array[1] will contain all objects with `day` as `tomorrow`, and so on

Now you can use it through the following code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [Array count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[Array objectAtIndex:section] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[[Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: there are not 3 sections sections are decide based on key called "day" i.e `today`,`tomorow` etc

Comment: I Know that why wrote Suppose, you need to write a logic to generate as many sub arrays as there are distinct values of your day variable.

Answer (score 0):

It will work for me please try it in *cellForRowAtIndexPath* method.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [_arrMytrips objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *day = [dict objectForKey:@"day"];
        if ([day isEqualToString:@"today"] && indexPath.section == 0) {

            cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"day"];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"day"];

        }else{
            cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"day"];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"day"];
        }
```

Hope it will help to you.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    arrayMain = @[yourArray];
    arraySection = [NSMutableArray array];
    [arrayMain enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        int flag = 0;
        for(NSDictionary *secObj in arraySection) {
            if ([secObj[@"day"] isEqualToString:obj[@"day"]]) {
                ++flag;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (flag == 0) {
            [arraySection addObject:obj];
        }
    }];
}
```

Then:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return arraySection.count;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfRows = [NSMutableArray array];

    [arrayMain enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if ([obj[@"day"] isEqualToString:arraySection[section][@"day"]]) {
            [arrayOfRows addObject:obj];
        }
    }];

    return arrayOfRows.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    NSMutableArray *arrayOfRows = [NSMutableArray array];

    [arrayMain enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if ([obj[@"day"] isEqualToString:arraySection[indexPath.section][@"day"]]) {
            [arrayOfRows addObject:obj];
        }
    }];

    NSDictionary *objectToShow = arrayOfRows[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = objectToShow[@"callbackSlotName"];

    return cell;
}
```

By this code you don't have to calculate anything just put it into you code and change the values accordingly. If you have any queries please feel free to ask.